# Simultaneous equating of partial derivative expressions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, systems-of-equations, applications

Algebraic geometers study the simultaneous vanishing of systems of multivariate polynomials.

I was wondering if this theme presents itself in partial differential equations and analysis. What I had in mind was, equating expressions of partial derivatives and asking when they are simultaneously equal.

An example of this might be something like:

$$\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial u^3}+v\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(u\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right) - v\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(v\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}$$

> Are these studied at all from a theoretical standpoint and/or a numerical standpoint?

Comment: It seems you are asking about systems of PDE's, which are indeed important